# AngularJS: Injecting $timeout not available in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, angularjs-timeout

I am injecting `$timeout` into the following directive but it is not defined.

The following code prints *undefined* to the console and throws *TypeError: $timeout is not a function*;

```
export default class foo {
    constructor ($timeout) {
        'ngInject';
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = {};
        this.$timeout = $timeout;

        console.log( $timeout );
        $timeout( function() {
            alert('timeout');
        }, 0 );
    }

    link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl ) {      
        ....
    }

    // Create an instance so that we can access this inside link
    static factory() {
        foo.instance = new foo();
        return foo.instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that **you're not injecting anything**, you're merely specifying a parameter `$timeout` which is acting as like a placeholder for a would-be injected service. To fix, add `foo.$inject = ['$timeout'];` to the end of your file as follows:

```
export default class foo {
    constructor ($timeout) {
        'ngInject';
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = {};
        this.$timeout = $timeout;

        console.log( $timeout );
        $timeout( function() {
            alert('timeout');
        }, 0 );
    }

    link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {      

    }

    // Create an instance so that we can access this inside link
    static factory() {
        foo.instance = new foo();
        return foo.instance;
    }
}

foo.$inject = ['$timeout'];
```

There are several examples [here on the sitepoint site](https://www.sitepoint.com/writing-angularjs-apps-using-es6/) which also go on to do the injection separately from the class defintions.

Or to **go through the static factory** (as you probably intended), it will be `foo.factory.$inject = ['$timeout']` at the end of the file, and you'll also have to tweak your factory function to take and pass on the injected service for you:

```
export default class foo {
    constructor ($timeout) {
        'ngInject';
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = {};
        this.$timeout = $timeout;

        console.log( $timeout );
        $timeout( function() {
            alert('timeout');
        }, 0 );
    }

    link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl ) {      

    }

    // Create an instance so that we can access this inside link
    static factory($timeout) {
        foo.instance = new foo($timeout);
        return foo.instance;
    }
}

foo.factory.$inject = ['$timeout'];
```